# Problem citing sources from references.tex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf, bibliographystyle

I am currently trying to format my thesis using Overleaf. I have attached a photo of my screen, which gives you a sense of how I have things set up. I have a file called references.tex. I am struggling to figure out how to add my references to this file so that I can cite sources. I am adapting this based on a university-provided LaTeX file, and there aren't instructions about how to do this. I realize this is incredibly vague, but any intuition or advice would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please never ever just show an image of code! Do you expect others to retype this in order to test it. Have you actually cited anything from the bibliography? Only those items cited will be listed in the bibliography. You're also using `\bibliography{diss}` does `diss.bib` exist?

Comment: The code posted should be enough to add the bibliography to your document, provided the documentation contains citations, the file diss.bib has entries with those citation keys, and bibtex is run in the compilation process (which Overleaf should do). Is the natbib package loaded in the preamble? Are you having trouble with the citations, `\cite{citekey}` and related commands? Or with adding entries to the .bib file? Or both? Read [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_bibliographies_on_Overleaf).

Comment: I just noticed that the left panel shows a file called `citations.bib`, but the `\bibliography` command tells it to look for a file `diss.bib`. If that's the bib file you intend to use, either rename the file to `diss.bib`, or change the `\bibliography` command to `\bibliography{citations}`.